# How to write PowerPoint slide change to a file?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to write to a file every time a slide is changed (next/back) in PowerPoint.

With presentation.pps I want to write in the file something like:

1. presentation - slide 1 - 11h04m03s
2. presentation - slide 2 - 11h04m34s

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Yes, this can be done, but please clarify what is considered a "change". Like a word is typed? Or a letter is typed? Or...?

Comment: ohh when we go to the next or previous slide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so here's what you need to do. Note one thing important - a PPS does not include a method to have a macro start upon opening the PPS. If you want that functionality, create an add-in (ppa) instead.

For the PPS, create a module and a class. (If you're not sure how to do this, you may need to study the Object Model more before continuing). The module can be named anything. Name the class "**clsWriteToFile**". In **clsWriteToFile**, put the following:

```
Public WithEvents PPTEvent As Application 'this is at the top of the class

Private Sub PPTEvent_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
'MsgBox ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(1).SlideNumber
'This is meant to illustrate that it is here you will write what you need to the file,
'like a slide number or time stamp, etc.
End Sub
```

In the module, put the following:

```
Public newPPTEvents As New clsWriteToFile
Sub StartLogging()
Set newPPTEvents.PPTEvent = Application
'this would be the location you either create the file or open an existing one.
End Sub
```

You'll need to write the code to read/write from a file. The FileSystemObject is useful in that regard.

To get this working with a PPS without going into the VBA, you'll have to have a manual trigger on the actual slide. An example would be to add a shape to the first slide, like a rounded rectange. Add it and type "Start Show". Then, add an **Action**. The action would be on "**Mouse_Click**"->"**Run Macro**" and then choose the **StartLogging** sub routine.

And that's it.

If you are using a PPA instead of a PPS, you could remove the need for the last step by just naming the "**StartLogging**" routine to "**Auto_Open**".

Comment: for powerpoint 2010, Auto_Open does not work any longer, read this instead:  http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/PowerPoint_Auto_Open_Code.html