# Call subroutine when a specific slide loads, or on a timer

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm working with a PowerPoint 2003 presentation for a kiosk display, and it is left running pretty much 24/7. One slide on it has the weather, the current date, and the 7 day forecast.

I've already written the subs that will update the weather from an Excel workbook, and update the dates displayed, but right now I have to manually update it when I come in. Is there a way that I can have a subroutine (e.g. `UpdateSlide()`) called when the slideshow reaches that particular slide? It seems like there is no official way to do this, I'm assuming for security reasons, but what about a timed event, such that it would call it say, every six hours?

Comment: I wouldn't guess security reasons. Look for some DOM event like OnSlideDisplay that you can act upon. (I don't know VBA).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the built-in `OnSlideShowPageChange` event:

```
Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
   If Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition = 3 Then
       'Perform Updates for slide #3
   EndIf
End Sub
```

Edit: As kcoppock pointed out, you can put this code in any module.

Comment: Stupid question (I'm new to VBA): where would I place this sub? Can it go into any module, or should I make a class module for it?

Comment: Nevermind, it WAS a stupid question. I just tested it by sticking into my primary module, and it worked great! Thanks!

Comment: That's a great one! I didn't know bout this event, in the past I was creating a class and using `SlideShowNextSlide`, but this is much easier!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The event [SlideShowNextSlide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211571(office.11).aspx) is what you need. See [How to write PowerPoint slide change to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880265/how-to-write-slide-powerpoint-change-to-a-file/1885825#1885825) for an example of how to use it.